# Magento 2 reindex, clean cache, chmod folders in 1 php script?

Tags: magento2, php

After every change I have to keep reindex, cleaning cache, and chmod 777 on var, app/etc and pub everytime. Is there any php script out there that can do all of this? Or an easier method that running the commands 1 by 1?

Answer (score 3):

U can make shell script on Linux Server named for example `mage.sh` which contains following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/*
```

when u have to run just go to ur root folder on command line & run `./mage.sh` & ur job will be done.

As per need of your command u can make script & run

Comment: If it's solved ur issue. Then please accept the answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ssh script - `deploy.sh`

-`MAGENTO` path to Magento root folder
-`MAGENTOBIN` path to Magento bin folder

Our script `deploy.sh`

```
MAGENTO = /home/magentoroot
MAGENTOBIN=/home/magentoroot/bin/magento

chmod -R 775 $MAGENTO/var $MAGENTO/pub

rm -rf $MAGENTO/var/view_preprocessed $MAGENTO/var/di
rm -rf $MAGENTO/pub/static/adminhtml $MAGENTO/pub/static/frontend $MAGENTO/pub/static/_requirejs

php $MAGENTOBIN setup:upgrade
php $MAGENTOBIN setup:di:compile
php $MAGENTOBIN setup:static-content:deploy
php $MAGENTOBIN indexer:reindex
php $MAGENTOBIN cache:flush
```